# Testing locally Azure Devops Server - Adding new user

Tags: azure-devops-server

I'm testing in a local environment an instance of Azure DevOps Server. I'm getting mad about adding some external users to the Team but I don't see the possibility.
I've google around and it says to select the "User" button but I don't have it.(doc [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-add-a-user-to-an-Azure-DevOps-project)).

I'm logged as Admin and I don't have any Active Directory conf set up on my local.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

[image: Example adding user]